# Linux file/directory ownership: I can cp a file but not backup via unison

Tags: file-permissions, ubuntu-18.04, unison, keybase, incron

I have a question on Linux file/directory ownership that is allowing me to copy a file using `cp`, but not back it up via the utility `unison`.  The problem appears to be in the change of ownership for a temp file of unison's.  I'd like to know how to correct this.

The file is in a directory structure that looks like:

```
/.../A/B/C/D.txt
```

Ownership & permissions look like:

```
A is root:root, 500 (rx)
B is me:root, 500 (rx)
C is me:root, 700 (rwx)
D.txt is me:root, 600 (rw)
```

If I `cp D.txt` to an identically owned and permissioned file structure on my desktop that starts at B, everything is fine.  On the other hand, if I use unison to copy the directory structure, it fails on an ownership change for a ".unison.D.txt.nnnnn" file.  Is there a fix?

> UNISON 2.48.3 started propagating changes at 02:53:54.51 on 20 Nov 2018
>
> [BGN] Copying B/C/D.txt from /.../A to /home/me/Desktop/ [ie to /home/me/Desktop/B/C/D.txt]
>
> Failed: Error in setting file ownership:
>   Operation not permitted [chown(/home/me/Desktop/B/C/.unison.testing.txt.a14bcb4fe76cb8c262af6a50e2043619.unison.tmp)]
>
> Failed [B/C/D.txt]: Error in setting file ownership:
>   Operation not permitted [chown(/home/me/Desktop/B/C/.unison.testing.txt.a14bcb4fe76cb8c262af6a50e2043619.unison.tmp)]
>
> UNISON 2.48.3 finished propagating changes at 02:53:54.51 on 20 Nov 2018

Background: I am trying to use unison & incron to backup Keybase's online file-system, which exists at `/run/user/1000/keybase/kbfs`.  Below that directory, I find a collection of folders are all owned by me:root.  All directories are mode 500 (rx), save my own (/.../kbfs/private/me) which is 700 (rwx).  All files are mode 600 (rw).  I want that mirrored on my desktop.

Comment: It looks to me that the error is not copying the file, but rather retaining the ownership permissions.  Is /home a local disk (if so, what partition type) or some kind of mount - and if the latter, is it using SMB, NFS or something else?

Comment: /home is a btrfs subvolume, @home which, with @ (root) are on the same primary partition of my SSD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem does not appear to be unison, but the fact that on one side of the copy is a filesystem run by keybase.  Keybase is allowing me to write into it's directory and reporting me:root ownership, but when unison tries to create a me:root file on my Desktop, it fails.  I understand that filesystems can pretty much report anything they want regarding permissions and behave any way they want regarding ability to read/write/execute.

The solution for unison is to use `group = false` to keep it from trying to sync the root ownership.  In that case, it also needs `perms = 0o1700` to avoid trying to set the root's or others' permission bits.

That works when unison is run from the cli, but is continuing to present problems when used with incrond - but that's for another question...